# Evaluating $\int_{\pi/4 }^{\pi /2}(2-\csc^2\theta )d\theta$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help evaluating the following integral:

> $$\displaystyle \int_{\pi/4 }^{\pi /2}(2-\csc^2\theta )d\theta$$

Comment: It helps to write questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Also, what are your thoughts on the problem? Regards

Comment: Pointer: it really helps us to help you if you include a little about what you've tried or where you're stuck.  (And users are more eager to help when a question demonstrates a little effort and/or thought).  When you *do* receive helpful answers, we encourage users to accept an answer (you can accept only *one* answer per question). To accept an answer, just click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Recall that $$\dfrac{d \cot(x)}{dx} = -\csc^2(x)$$To put it the other way (by fundamental theorem of calculus), we have
$$\int \csc^2(x) dx = -\cot(x)$$
Move the mouse over the gray area for the complete answer.

> We have$$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}(2-\csc^2(x))dx = \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} 2dx - \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\csc^2(x)dx = \left. 2 x + \cot(x) \right \vert_{x=\pi/4}^{x=\pi/2} = \dfrac{\pi}2 - 1$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. Edited.